# Deserialize lists within a .dat file to a text box using b formatter

Tags: c#, loops, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have created an application that will save lists to a .dat file using a binary formatter and serializing the list.

I wish to then de serialize this list and display this within a text box.

Furthermore, I have tried using a for each loop to get every object from the list, but it won't continue through the rest of the lists and stops at the first list stored within the file.

I have been tasked with binary formatter even though Ive been informed its obsolete.

Comment: yeah I tried that it doesnt fix it I think I need to edit my loop conditions but unsure

Comment: thats just a string to use for my file location

Comment: bit lost but its declared as const and it will also have the vaule, that loop works kinda it will load up one list fine it just doesnt read all the lists stored in the file

Comment: _"that will save lists to a .dat file using a binary formatter"_ - [don't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-7.0#remarks). [Deserialization risks in use of BinaryFormatter and related types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
var totalList = new List<InPerson>();
do
{
    var subList = (List<InPerson>)bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile);
    totalList.AddRange(subList);
} while (!inFile.EndOfStream);

foreach (InPerson a in totalList)
    txtBookings.Text += a.ToString();

//maybe set InPersonLIst to totalList
InPersonList = totalList;
```

This assumes that instead of **1** list with **many** items, there are **many** lists with **many** items.

This structure seems odd to say the least, you should consider having 1 list with many items.